# How to use spring.schemas and spring.handlers to short-circuit dependcies' schema lookups

Tags: spring, mule

I'm trying to upgrade https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-cache to run under Mule 3.4.0 CE but getting the following when running `mvn clean install` on the command line

```
[10-16 13:51:05] WARN  XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main]: Ignored XML validation warning org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
....
testExternalGenerator(org.mule.module.cache.ExpressionTest): Line 6 in XML document from URL [jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.4.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
```

This appears due to mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar's mule-spring-config.xml's declaration using `current`.  If this were my config file I'd modify the file to explicitly point to the URI I want, but, alas, it is not.  Here's line 6:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd"
```

Is there a way for me to use the [Spring handler/schema approach](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration) to have *current* point to *3.1*?

```
http:\//www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd=META-INF/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
```

Or is there a different approach I need to be taking?

Comment: Did you check my fork that compiles on 3.4.0? https://github.com/ddossot/mule-module-cache

Comment: I previously did not -- just checked it out and my problems are no longer occurring.  This solved my immediate issue.

Comment: [Mirrors](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) may also have worked for me here, but I suspect there were other issues with the mule-config file.

Answer (score 0):

The URI for the current Spring Beans schema is:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

not:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
```

Comment: But how do I have my application point to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` when the xsd in the Mule library explicitly calls `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd`?  What I'm trying to do is to intercept the call to get the xsd at the location defined in the framework jar.  [This issue](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/strange_spring_problem_running_functiontest) appears to be reporting the same problem, but has no resolution.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the core issue you're facing then.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: I'm using Mule CE 3.4.0, which includes jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.4.0/mule-module-spring-config-3.4.0.jar.  This jar (which is a Mule jar, not one of my own making) has an xsd that defines `xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd"`.  I think this is what's causing my problem, but to solve it the only way I know how would be to modify the xsd in the Mule jar that I downloaded, place that version of the jar back in (cont)

Comment: (from previous) my local Maven repo.  I'm hoping there's a less hacky way for me to tell Maven to point somewhere other than where the Mule xsd is telling it to.  Hopefully this is confusing because there's a simple solution to the problem I'm facing.  Basically, it appears that the Mule jar's xsd is wrong, but it seems like I would not be the first person to catch this so something is likely wrong with my local setup.  http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/strange_spring_problem_running_functiontest seems to be saying that the xsd needs to be changed, but I don't have access to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question then you would create a file called **spring.schemas**, store it in the **META-INF** directory of your WAR or EAR file and have it contain the following entry:

```
http:\//www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
```

If you want not to grab the XSD from the internet, then you add the following entry:

```
http:\//www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
```

The second one assumes that the appropriate spring-beans.jar is in your classpath.  The final option to my knowledge is to change the entry in the SpringConfig.xml file from:

```
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd"
```

to

```
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
```